# HTML5 datetime min attribute

Tags: forms, html, datetimepicker

In a HTML5 website, I use the new datetime input type field with an alternative for old browsers.

In my case, the datetime field is used to set an upcoming event so it must be impossible to set a datetime defined in the past. The min attribute should allow me to do that but it seems to not work whereas it does the job on date or time input fields.

Here is my code (edit View, but same problem in add View) :

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="EventDatetime" name="data[Event][datetime]" step="900" min="<?php echo date(DATE_RFC3339); ?>" value="<?php echo $event->date; ?>" required/>
```

which should give :

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="EventDatetime" name="data[Event][datetime]" step="900" min="2012-10-01T13:05:00+02+00" value="2012-11-01T13:05:00+02+00" required/>
```

If I check this code in the inspector (Chrome, Opera...), the `min` tag does not exist, if I try to get it in javascript, I get `undefined`. However, this tag is present in the source code (via Ctrl+U in the browser). I don't understand....

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: I see the `min` in the inspector, with your exact code (copy/pasted).

Comment: I have tested the code with Opera 12.02 and Chrome 21 and everything works fine, did you make your HTML page HTML5 compliant, i.e. by adding on top <!doctype html> ?

Comment: If I submit my page to the validator, I get the following error: ` Bad value 2012-10-01T14:24:39+02:00 for attribute min on element input: The literal did not satisfy the local datetime format.`, there is no other error according to the W3C validator (with the HTML5 experimental validator)

Answer (score 1):

The inspector doesn't reflect your real source, but generate a code source base on the page Dom.

W3C specification specify that Date input must have a min attribute (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#local-date-and-time-state-type-datetime-local). When the inspector generate the source code you see it add the default attribut min.

Edit
Your min attribut is not show because you don't use the good format. HTML dates format is  1970-01-01T00:00:00.0 not 2012-10-01T13:05:00+02+00.

Comment: I agree with you but it doesn't tell me why the min attribute is ignored.